# Como passar parâmetro para Index de outro Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, parâmetros, controller

Tenho que passar um parâmetro (ID) para o index de um controler,

Tentei usar o `ActionLink` mas não funcionou.

View:

```
<body>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Tag)
            </th> 
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Fluido)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Vedacao)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Criticidade)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Mtbf)
            </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tag)
        </th>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fluido)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Vedacao)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Criticidade)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Mtbf)
        </td>
        <td>       
            @Html.ActionLink("Detalhes", "Index", "RelatorioRa", new { tagId = item.TagID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Controler `RelatorioRa` que ira receber o ID:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int? tagId)
    {
        var relatorioRaModels = db.RelatorioRaModels.Include(r => r.RelatorioTag);

        if (tagId.HasValue)
        {
            //realiza o filtro para a tag selecionada
            relatorioRaModels = relatorioRaModels.Where(a => a.TagID == tagId);
        }

        return View(await relatorioRaModels.ToListAsync());
    }
```

Comment: Amigo, o exemplo que lhe respondi na outra pergunta mostra como fazer isso é o `@Html.ActionLink(linkText: item.Tag, actionName: "Index", controllerName: "RelatoriosRas", routeValues: new { tagId = item.TagID }, htmlAttributes: new { })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nessa sua situação, bastaria você acrescentar mais um parâmetro no seu [`ActionLink`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx) que seria referente ao `htmlAttributes`

```
@Html.ActionLink("Detalhes", "Index", "RelatorioRa", new { tagId = item.TagID }, null)
```

Se você passar somente três parâmetros, ele entende que o seu `new { tagId = item.TagID }` é o `htmlAttributes` e que o `RelatorioRa` é o `routeValues`.

Comment: Amigo pode me explicar porque usar assim: `@Html.ActionLink("Detalhes", "Index", "RelatorioRa", new { tagId = item.TagID })` não funciona? e do jeito que vc passou funciona?

Comment: É por causa da assinatura do `ActionLink` https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Cara, to te devendo uma cerveja, rs obrigado em valeu

Comment: bora beber então